# Where the object exist in reality?

Tags: optics, thought-experiment

Suppose the object O exists at some point(x,y) in space, and two observers A and B watching object O at the same distance d, they will observe at the same distance as they have same focal length in their eyes, etc.

What if the observer A have different focal length and observer B have different, each will see Object O at different distance d1 and d2 respectively, So where is exactly the Object O is in the universe or what is reality?

Comment: "the object O exists at some point (x,y) in space"

Comment: its all relative I guess

Comment: That's not how our eyes measure distance to an object. Changing the focal length of the eyes of each observer would just make object O blurry in different ways.

Comment: @probably_someone what if there is a change in radius of curvature?

Comment: @satsvelke A change in radius of curvature of the lens of the eye just changes the focal length, which, again, just makes the object blurry.

Comment: even the blind can measure a distance

Answer (score 1):

The distance of an object has nothing to do with the focal length. You can estimate the distance only with the different pictures in your two eyes, or by moving one eye and observe the difference.

Comment: or by vergence, or by accomodation, in theory, as I think we are not very good at using them in practice